# Stolen Phone - Why Pairing to Second Account is Allowed?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia

1. I was unable to find/block the phone via Find my Phone.
2. My MS account is still associated to my phone.
3. By now the phone has a different owner and it is associated to a second MS account, probably.
4. My carrier does not maintain an IMEI blacklist.

**Since MS knows the IMEI, why it allows pairing to a second account?**

From a technical point of view, forbidding the association to a second account (or asking for permission from first account) seems fairly simple. Even blocking the phone via internet seems simple as long as you know the IMEI.

MS Support was unable to help me (they had problems understanding what I am asking).

Thank you.

Comment: Your question presumes that the phone has been paired to a second MS account. How do you know that to be the case? How do you know the phone is even turned on and being used? Also, have you tried contacting your carrier? You say they do not maintain an IMEI blacklist, but they don't have to, there are also shared registers used by multiple carriers.

Comment: @Indrek The phone was stolen weeks ago. Most likely it is already sold and used. I have contacted the carrier (Orange): "no law says we must block the phone". My guess is MS and carriers are making more money this way.

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure what we can do for you. Was your phone set up with [Reset Protection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10549/microsoft-account-protect-my-phone)? If not, then it's probably been wiped.

Comment: @Indrek I do not expect to find the phone or retrieve any data. I just want to understand why MS allows pairing a second account to a stolen phone. As I said  an internet connection and the IMEI are enough to identify the phone and block the second account or the phone. Since this is technically doable, what stops MS from taking action? Reset Protection was turned off.

Comment: Well, if the IMEI was never blacklisted and Reset Protection was not enabled, why should Microsoft prevent resetting the phone and setting it up with a new account? How are they to know the phone didn't change hands legally?

Comment: @Indrek MS explicitly instructs the seller to remove the device from account.If you're no longer the owner, there is no sense in keeping the device associated to your account.Why would an honest seller keep the device associated to his account? If the seller is dishonest he can do all kind of things, including selling the device and keep Reset Protection on. So, I think the best scenario is to consider that the first account belongs to the honest owner.

Comment: Microsoft can instruct lots of things, people will still put phone's up for sale without even doing so much as a factory reset. A phone being wiped and set up with a different MS account is simply not enough to assume theft. At least that's my opinion. If you want Microsoft's official stance, you should contact them directly, all we can do here is speculate.

Comment: @Indrek MS support was unable to give a straight answer.